# Stored procedure for login not working as intended

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables, users, Roles, and User_Roles.

```
CREATE TABLE [Web].[Users]
(
    [Employee_ID] [Nvarchar] (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Username] [nvarchar] (25) NOT NULL,
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [Web].[Roles]
(
    [Role_ID] [Int] NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Roles] [nvarchar] (25) NOT NULL,
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [Web].[User_Roles]
(
    [Employee_ID] [Nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Role_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_ID 
        FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES [Web].[Users] (Employee_ID) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Role_ID 
        FOREIGN KEY (Role_ID) REFERENCES [Web].[Roles] (Role_ID),
    CONSTRAINT pk_User_Roles PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID, Role_ID)
);
```

The way it works is, when you login, it checks your Username against the `Employee_ID` in `Users` table, then goes to the `User_Roles` table and matches the `Employee_ID` it got from the `Users` table to the `User_Roles` table. Then it gets the `Role_ID` from the `User_Roles` table and matches the `Role_ID` to the roles in the `Roles` table.

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that does the checks and so far I've gotten close, but I feel I'm missing something. Hoping I can get help with it. This is what I have so far.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Web].[Get_User_Roles]
    @Username NVARCHAR(25)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Employee_ID Nvarchar, @Role_ID INT

    SELECT @Employee_ID = @Employee_ID, @Role_ID = @Role_ID
    FROM [Web].[Users] 
    WHERE @Employee_ID = @Employee_ID AND @Role_ID = @Role_ID 

    IF @Employee_ID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT @Employee_ID FROM [Web].Users 
                       WHERE @Username = Username)
        BEGIN
            SELECT 
                @Employee_ID [Employee_ID],
                (SELECT @Role_ID FROM User_Roles
                 WHERE @Role_ID = @Role_ID) [Roles]-- User Valid
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SELECT -2 [@Username], '' [Roles]--User not activated
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT -1 [@Username], '' [Roles]-- User invalid
    END
END
```

Any help to improve this would be appreciated. I put the tables code above so that it's available. My final outcome I shall ask again in this section as well as the middle. The way it works is, when you login, it checks your Username against the Employee_ID in Users Table, then goes to the User_Roles table and matches the Employee_ID it got from the Users table to the User_Roles table. Then it gets the Role_ID from the User_Roles table and matches the Role_ID to the Roles in the Roles table. I'm trying to make a stored procedure that does the checks and so far I've gotten close, but I feel I'm missing something. Hoping I can get help with it. This is what I have so far.

Comment: `select @Employee_ID = @Employee_ID, @Role_ID = @Role_ID`? What purpose is that statement meant to serve? it'll just set the value of `@Employee_ID` to the value of `@Employee_ID`; which is pointless because it *is* `@Employee_ID`.

Comment: I was told it needed to be set so as to put the 2 values together in the stored procedure

Comment: But `select @Employee_ID = @Employee_ID, @Role_ID = @Role_ID from [Web].[Users] WHERE @Employee_ID = @Employee_ID and @Role_ID = @Role_ID` *literally* makes no sense. What is that trying to achieve?

Comment: No you weren't told incorrectly, you coded it incorrectly. You are checking if the value of a variable equals the value of the variable which is pointless. You should check if the value of the variable equals the value of a column in the table. You have many challenges in the code you posted. Every time you reference a variable it is not what you want to do. You have varchar with no size. This thing needs a complete rebuild.

Comment: @SeanLange I think it's obvious I coded it incorrectly, hence why I'm asking for help to fix it. I just made some changes that you suggested. I'll edit in a minute.

Comment: The problem here is that the code is so far from correct it is impossible to decipher what you are trying to accomplish. This looks like it should be just a single query. What is the -2 and -1 supposed to indicate? You did a great job posting the ddl but I can't for the life of me figure out what you expect as output.

Comment: The -1 and -2 indicate User activated and User Invalid.

Comment: So -1 means there is a user but they have no roles? And -2 means the user doesn't exist? And if they do have roles what do you want returned? I think you are wanting to have your procedure return different result sets under some conditions?

Comment: @SeanLange  -1 means the user doesn't exist at all. -2 means user exist, but no roles have been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this part is not going to work at all:

```
        select @Employee_ID = @Employee_ID, @Role_ID = @Role_ID
    from [Web].[Users] WHERE @Employee_ID = @Employee_ID and @Role_ID = @Role_ID
```

You are comparing variables with themselves in the WHERE Statement, you are assigning variables to each other, and you have no Role_ID in the [Web].[Users] table. Try the following

```
SELECT Employee_ID, Roles
FROM  [Web].[Users] A
INNER JOIN  [Web].[User_Roles] B
 ON A.[Employee_ID] = B.[Employee_ID]
INNER JOIN [Web].[Roles] C
 ON b.[Role_ID] = C.[Role_ID]
WHERE [Username] = @Username
```

This code will return the Employee_id and Roles if you have a user with that username, or an empty data set otherwise.

Comment: maybe use left joins so it is clear what is missing?

Comment: @Hogan i think you would only want to grab users that actually have some role attached to them. But yes, if it is acceptable to have users without a role, we could use Left joins.

Comment: @Alex is correct. We only want users with Roles. If no roles, then no login acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Still not very clear what you want as output but I think it would be something like this. This will return -2 in the UserStatus column if there isn't a role for the user. Otherwise it will return 1 in that column and the Role. You should just check if there are rows returned when you call this. If it returns no rows then the user doesn't exist.

```
select UserStatus = case when ur.Role_ID is null then -2 else 1 end
    , r.Roles
from Web.Users u
left join Web.User_Roles ur on ur.Employee_ID = u.Employee_ID
left join Web.Roles r on r.Role_ID = ur.Role_ID
where u.Username = @Username
```

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Role-based-security-using-Forms-Authentication-in-ASPNet.aspx This is where I was pulling the original code. This might help you. My output depends on the user inputting a valid Username. Then it checks Username against Employee_ID. Then that Employee_ID against Role_ID. Then that Role_ID against Roles. After all that checking, it pops back Valid Username with a Role or Invalid user or valid user with no role.

Comment: I would run away as quickly as possible from that example. The very first line of sql was enough for me. They are receiving password in clear text and storing it in the table as clear text. And the logic is tragically flawed. If a user has more than 1 role the code in that example will only return a single role. You can find MUCH better examples of how to do this sort of thing.